# How to make a full windows 7 hardrive shared on a home network for macs?

Tags: windows-7, windows, macos, networking, wireless-networking

This my setup:

- 1 PC - with a 1 TB Hardrive called E:/  (Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit)
- 1 Mac Apple Mac Book Pro (Mac OSX Yosemite)
- 2 Windows Laptop (Both with Windows 7 Pro 64bit)
- 1 Router

I want to make my PC with the Harddrive a shared cloud drive for my home network. Where I can dump and share backup files and easily access the folder from my mac and windows machines over wifi. I want it to be fast and Dropbox is not an option even though I use a Pro account

Can anyone advice what to do here - homegroup does not work.

What software or tools can I do to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried just turning on Sharing on the 1TB E: drive?  Macs (and certainly the other PC's) can access a shared drive.  On the Mac, you might be able to browse the Network, or at least use the "Connect to Server" option, using something like `smb://mybigpc/e-drive/`.  You'll need a local account on the PC, with the appropriate permissions to the Share and to the drive, and you'll need to enter those credentials from the Mac (and other PC's, probably) when you connect to the share.

Comment: I have already tried sharing but no luck. Someone just said NAS drives.

Comment: I had a NAS for years, and it might work for you.  But, if you use Fast User Switching on the Mac, be aware that only one account on the Mac can mount the NAS at a time.  Shouldn't be an issue if you're just accessing from different computers, though.